# Is it possible to write all validation messages in single ts file reuse it in reactive forms

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

> Im writing these validations for every file in every component.ts
> where the validations is required
>
> is it possible to write all these in single ts file and reuse where
> ever needed

```
 validationmessages = {
    username: [
      { type: 'required', message: 'Username is required.' },
    ],
    password: [
      { type: 'required', message: 'Password is required.' }
    ],
    email: [
      { type: 'required', message: 'Email is required.' },
    ]

  };
constructor(private route: Router, private formbuilder: FormBuilder,
                private userservice: UserService, private commondata: CommonData) {

this.loginform = this.formbuilder.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
```

Comment: What is the problem with what you have now? Looks like they're in a single file to me. Just use the same validationmessages instead of copying it everywhere.

Comment: in my current project i have login form, signup form, manager creation form, agent creation form and many where I have first name, last name, dob, phn number and so on as common inputs. now I'm writing validations messages for each ts file is it possible to write in different ts file and reuse same when ever required in different components.  like for password and confirm password we wrte in different ts file and call that function .

Answer (score 1):

You can `export` a `const` variable from a ts file

validationMsg.ts

```js
export const validationmessages = {
    username: [
      { type: 'required', message: 'Username is required.' },
    ],
    password: [
      { type: 'required', message: 'Password is required.' }
    ],
    email: [
      { type: 'required', message: 'Email is required.' },
    ]

};
```

and `import` it afterwards

sometsfile.ts

```js
import {validationmessages} from './validationMsg.ts'; //or correct path..
```

read more about [Modules in Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

[Simple stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7qtwp1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: not working for me, can you provide stackblitz

Comment: I added a simple example my friend